# Pushing data into my application in automation testing

Tags: android, automation, automated-tests

I automate android application and I need automation tool that can push data into started activity in my tests (by Intent or somehow else). I tried appium but it can only start new activity with intent action which registered in Manifest.
Are there any such tools at all? Or maybe other way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in **BroadcastReceiver**. You can create it in the main activity and wait for the custom intent, which is sent via ADB using Appium. Thus, I was able to change the data application runtime

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple Android app/service without any UI elements, which can pass the required data via intent or some other means you wanted. This android app/service should be designed in such a way that you can invoke the required functionality via adb cmds. For example your app can continuously read a file , which you can push via adb. Define your own cmds and write those cmds in the file. push the file to android device via adb. your app can read this file, extract the cmd and invoke required method to share the data to another app.

Let say SEND_DATA is the cmd defined to share the data with the another android app

From PC:

```
echo SEND_DATA > cmd.txt
adb push cmd.txt /SomewhereInAndroidDevice
```

From Your Android App:

```
loop
{
    if /SomewhereInAndroidDevice/cmd.txt:
        read /SomewhereInAndroidDevice/cmd.txt;
        if(cmd == SEND_DATA)
            call required method to send data to another APP;
        deleate /SomewhereInAndroidDevice/cmd.txt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution! I will definitely try to implement it as an alternative)